# Changing grid depending on device orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the size of divs depending of screen size.
If the phone is laying it changes the sizes of divs.

Example:

**block is default: 330px width and 250px high on a 768x1280 screen resolution.**

The factor is:

```
width: 330px; factor x 2,18
height: 250px; factor x 5,12
```

When i change my phone to laying the sizes should be:

```
width: 587px 
height: 150px
```

which doesnt work in the first place, can someone tell my why not?

js:

```
var devicewidth = $( window ).width();
var deviceheight = $( window ).height();
var mbwsize = devicewidth / 2.18;
var mbhsize = deviceheight / 5.12;
var mbisize = mbhsize / 1.25;
$('#mainmenublok').css('width', mbwsize+'px');
$('#mainmenublok').css('height', mbhsize+'px');
$('#mainmenublok').css('background-size', mbisize+'px'+mbisize+'px');
```

dont get errors, it just keeps the content in the middle as `720px width (768 - offset)`

I changed the main div already here:

`$('#maintable').css('width', devicewidth+'px');`

Will try to change window to document but can someone look at this?

With document it doesnt change either.
The calculation is correct if you look at the picture at the debug.

I also tried it in a function but that did not work.

Added a picture to explain what happens

explain: [image]

debug: [image]

Comment: did you try to log your variables (mbwsize, mbhsize, etc..) to your console to see if the outcome is right?

Comment: yes that is the one you see at: new width, height and icon size

Comment: Any reason to not use media queries in CSS, which are the proper tool for the job?

Comment: right...didnt check the pictures...my bad. Can you show the html you're applying it to?

Comment: @Chris well i do that but that is only for detecting devices 720px or higher (blackberry q10 or z10) what im trying to do is making it work for android devices so the grids (and everything else in the app) looks right

Comment: @mf82  html is just something easy like:
<div onclick="bb.pushScreen('timeline.html', 'timeline');" class="mainmenublok" id="blocktimeline" style="background-image:url(ico/timeline.png); background-size:200px 200px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:center;">
<img id="pictimeline" src="ico/bbaction.png" width="50" height="50" style="display:none;">
</div>

The Style in this is just the default size (based on 768x1280) the javascript changes this (well it should)

Comment: Then you should try to target it with jquery "$('.mainmenublok').css('width', mbwsize+'px'); Notice the dot instead of the hash...hashtags are for ID's in CSS.

Comment: oh my god... how could i ever miss that! let me try

Comment: So, what's the verdict? Did you get it to work? Because then I will document my suggestion in an answer format and you can mark your question as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the HTML provided by the author in the comments

```
<div onclick="bb.pushScreen('timeline.html', 'timeline');"class="mainmenublok" id="blocktimeline" style="background-image:url(ico/timeline.png); background-size:200px 200px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:center;"> 
   <img id="pictimeline" src="ico/bbaction.png" width="50" height="50" style="display:none;"> 
</div>
```

and the js used as shown above, I suggest to use `$('.mainmenublok').css('width', mbwsize+'px');` instead of `$('#mainmenublok').css('width', mbwsize+'px');`. Dots are used to indicate classes in CSS, as hashtags are used to indicate ID's.

Comment: Thanks, it working :) just calculating the rest of the app using the same way

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [mediaqueries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) or [device.js](https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js)?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to achieve by script.... Is okay but in some browser it may give you bugs ... better you try with any of the css frameworks like twitter bootstrap its not really huge.... the your site will be responsive as according to your device....